# Why do my attempts to fit Planck's law fail?

Tags: fitting, physics

I have some [data](https://pastebin.com/MGEzkeC3) and want to fit it to Planck's law for black body radiation. The problem is that Mathematica does not give me the correct coefficients.

When I evaluate

```
dati = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/MGEzkeC3", "Table"];
h = 6.62607004*10^(-34);
c = 299792458;
kb = 1.38064852*10^(-23);
Planks[l_, T_, A_] := (1/A)*(((2*h*c^2)/l^5)*(1/(Exp[((h*c)/(l*kb*T))] - 1)));
fittesana2 = FindFit[dati, Planks[l, T, A], {T, A } , l];
Show[
  Plot[fittesana2[l], {l, 400, 900}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], 
  ListPlot[dati], Frame -> True]
Pfit = NonlinearModelFit[dati, Planks[l, T, A], {{A, 1*10^8}, {T, 1700}}, l];
Show[
  Plot[Pfit[l], {l, 400, 900}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All],
  ListPlot[dati], Frame -> True]
Normal[Pfit]
Pfit["ANOVATable"]
Pfit["ParameterTable"]
Pfit["FitCurvatureTable"]
```

I get

[image]

Sorry guys for forgetting to write down constants. And my data is only the part of Black Body radiation law. And unit of x-axis is nanometers(nm), and y-axis (uW/cm^2/nm).
**Update:** As suggested by @JimB, I changed my fitting function. I tried to use @JimB suggested function, but for me easier was different one, because I need to find out temperature (Te). Here is the code:

```
h = 6.62607004*10^(-34);
c = 299792458;
kb = 1.38064852*10^(-23);
b = 2*6.62607004*10^(-34)*299792458^2*Pi;
d = (6.62607004*10^(-34)*299792458)/(1.38064852*10^(-23));
dati = ImportString[Import["H2liesma.txt"], "Table"];
Plankulis[la_, Te_, G_, b_, d_] := (1/G)*(b/(la^5*(Exp[d/(la*Te)] - 1)));
Pfit3 = FindFit[dati, 
   Plankulis[la, Te, G, b, d], {G, 1*10^(9)}, { Te, 1500} , la];
Show[Plot[Pfit3[la], {la, 400, 900}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> All], ListPlot[dati], Frame -> True]
```

I get:

```
  FindFit::nonopt: Options expected (instead of la) beyond position 4 in FindFit[{{400.035,-0.00759963},{400.409,0.0136996},{400.783,-0.000465753},{401.157,0.00636862},{401.531,0.0205706},{401.904,0.0257837},{402.278,0.0298773},{402.652,0.00226108},{403.025,0.0188769},{403.399,-0.0230916},{403.772,-0.00365794},{404.146,0.00856837},<<28>>,{414.961,-0.00272152},{415.333,-0.00222349},{415.706,-0.00943255},{416.078,-0.00921836},{416.45,0.00204648},{416.823,-0.0261218},{417.195,-0.00775242},{417.567,0.0140285},{417.939,-0.00992257},{418.311,-0.00711655},<<1408>>},<<24>>/<<1>>,{<<1>>},<<1>>,la]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>
```

When I write analitical solution for my function:

```
b = 2*6.62607004*10^(-34)*299792458^2*Pi;
d = (6.62607004*10^(-34)*299792458)/(1.38064852*10^(-23));
Plankulis1[la_] := (1/G)*(b/(la^5*(Exp[d/(la*Te)] - 1)));
Te = 1500;
G = 1*10^(9);
Plankulis[G, b, la, d, Te]
Plot[Plankulis1[la], {la, 400*10^(-9), 
  700*10^(-8)}, {PlotRange -> Full},  Frame -> True]
```

I get:
[image]

I get out what I need.
What is it I am doing wrong? I did not really understood it in answers. Thank you.

Comment: What are the units of your data supposed to be?

Comment: Are you sure that you data follows the BlackBody radiation emission?

Comment: If you're certain that your fitting function is correct, try giving initial guesses for the free parameters you're fitting. If the correct values are very large or very small, `FindFit` might get stuck in some local optimum. I suspect that your value for `A` might need a nudge in the right direction. You can also try to fit the logarithm of your parameters (e.g., replace `A -> Exp[logA]` in the formula), since that makes it easier for the fitting algorithm to cover a large range of magnitudes.

Comment: Where in your code do you define `h`, `c`, and `kb` ?

Comment: @Jim, OP seems to be assuming that everybody knows Planck's constant, the speed of light, and Boltzmann's constant. It was remiss of him/her to omit the values of those, which would also have given a clue on what units s/he was using.

Comment: @J.M. Yes.  I finally figured out $h$ and $c$ but not $k_b$.  (To state the obvious: I don't do physics well.)  It turns out to solve for $a$ and $t$ and make predictions (assuming the correct curve and/or data) one doesn't need to know any of those constants.

Comment: @Jim, yes, that just amounts to finding the [first and second radiation constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#First_and_second_radiation_constants) from the data for a given temperature.

Comment: It looks like you used `FindFit[]` wrong: try `FindFit[dati, Plankulis[la, Te, G, b, d], {{G, 1*10^9}, {Te, 1500}}, la]`.

Comment: @Andra please, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Correction:***  What a difference good starting values can make.  What I presented earlier totally missed values of the parameters that allow for a good fit.

Using a simpler parameterization with `A -> 2 a c^2 h` and `T -> (c h t)/kb` we have the equation

```
1/(a (-1 + E^(1/(l t))) l^5)
```

$$\frac{1}{a l^5 \left(e^{\frac{1}{l t}}-1\right)}$$

Using `FindFit` with good starting values (suggested by @SimonWoods) we have the following:

```
sol = FindFit[dati, 1/(a (-1 + E^(1/(l t))) l^5), {{a, 1/(6 10^24)}, {t, 0.00007}}, l]
(* {a -> 5.707889613047356`*^-24,t -> 0.00007085381301746858`} *)
Show[Plot[1/(a (-1 + E^(1/(l t))) l^5) /. sol, {l, 400, 900}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.02], Red}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[dati, PlotStyle -> White]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

Comment: I disagree - what about `t = 0.0001` for example

Comment: @SimonWoods  You are correct.  I didn't try enough values of `t`.  I'll work on correcting my answer.

Comment: @JimB I am curious about how `t` can be thought as negative if it is defined by means of positive quantities...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas I wasn't advocating a negative value for `t` or implying a physical meaning for it.  I was just trying different values of `t` and saw (for the limited range of values I tried) that there just seemed to be two shapes of curves.  Fortunately Simon Woods pointed out my error.

Answer (score 1):

No need what JimB did. Just correct the units for $\lambda$, i.e., not nanometers but meters. There was also some errors in the syntax when using `FindFit`. I also add `pts`as a new dataset with less points suitable for plotting and compare to the fits.

Here is your code corrected:

```
dati = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/MGEzkeC3", "Table"];
pts = dati[[#]] & /@ Table[i, {i, 1, 1458, 50}];
h = 6.62607004*10^(-34);
c = 299792458;
kb = 1.38064852*10^(-23);
Planks[l_, T_, A_] := (2*h*c^2 10^45)/(A l^5 (Exp[(10^9 h*c)/(l*kb*T)] - 1));
fittesana2 = FindFit[dati, Planks[l, T, A], {{A, 1*10^8}, {T, 1700}}, l];
Plot[Planks[l, T, A] /. fittesana2, {l, 400, 900}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
PlotRange -> All, Epilog :> {Blue, PointSize[0.015], Point[pts]}]
Pfit = NonlinearModelFit[dati, 
Planks[l, T, A], {{A, 1*10^8}, {T, 1700}}, l]
Plot[Pfit[l], {l, 400, 900}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, 
Epilog :> {Blue, PointSize[0.015], Point[pts]}]
Normal[Pfit]
Pfit["ANOVATable"]
Pfit["ParameterTable"]
Pfit["FitCurvatureTable"]
```

The results with `FindFit`:

[image]

and with `NonLinearModel Fit`:

[image]

Adicional data:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]